# a list will not join the scond time but will the first time

Tags: python, string, list, passwords

i wanted to turn a list into a string for an auto password generator
this is the code:

```
import random
import string

print("hello welcome to the random password generator! ")
level_of_password = input("what level do you want your password to be?(weak, medium, strong): ")

list_of_words_for_password = ["obama", "apples", "mom", "your", "cyber"]
if level_of_password == "weak":
    weak_password = list(random.sample(list_of_words_for_password, 2))
    weak_password = "".join(weak_password)
    print(weak_password)

elif level_of_password == "medium":
    letters_for_password = list(string.ascii_letters)
    numbers_for_password = []
    for i in range(random.randint(10, 30)):
        numbers_for_password.append(random.randint(5, 10))
    letters_and_numbers_for_password = numbers_for_password + letters_for_password
    medium_password = [random.sample(letters_and_numbers_for_password, random.randint(5, 20))]
    medium_password = "".join(medium_password)
```

for the weak password it converts the list into a string just fine
but for the medium password, if I try to print it it gives me this error:

```
line 27, in <module>
    medium_password = "".join(medium_password)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

why can I join the list of charecters for my medium password like I did for the weak one.

also, im learning python by myself, if you see something in the code that is unbearable to you, please let me know that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find comments inline

```py
import random
import string

print("hello welcome to the random password generator! ")
level_of_password = input("what level do you want your password to be?(weak, medium, strong): ")

list_of_words_for_password = ["obama", "apples", "mom", "your", "cyber"]
if level_of_password == "weak":
    weak_password = list(random.sample(list_of_words_for_password, 2))
    weak_password = "".join(weak_password)
    print(weak_password)

elif level_of_password == "medium":
    letters_for_password = list(string.ascii_letters)
    numbers_for_password = []
    for i in range(random.randint(10, 30)):
        numbers_for_password.append(random.randint(5, 10))
    letters_and_numbers_for_password = numbers_for_password + letters_for_password
    #------>
    medium_password = random.sample(letters_and_numbers_for_password, random.randint(5, 20)) # remove extra []
    #               ^^^^                                                                   ^^^^
    medium_password = "".join(map(str, medium_password)) # convert intergers to string
    #                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    print(medium_password)
```